# Simple fallback progressbar when tqdm is not available

Tags: python, progress, fallback, tqdm

I have a python package that uses the [`tqdm`](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) progressbar. However, I don't want this to be a hard dependency for the users of my package. Is there some simple drop-in solution that can easily act as fallback if `tqdm` is not installed?

I am using the `total` and `leave` property of `tqdm.tqdm()`, as well as the `update` and `close` methods of the `tqdm.tqdm` instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.

```
def noobar(itrble, desc):
  """Simple progress bar. To be used if tqdm not installed."""
  L  = len(itrble)
  print('{}: {: >2d}'.format(desc,0), end='')
  for k,i in enumerate(itrble):
    yield i
    p = (k+1)/L
    e = '' if k<(L-1) else '\n'
    print('\b\b\b\b {: >2d}%'.format(int(100*p)), end=e)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Try it with

```
from time import sleep
for i in noobar(range(5),"my work"):
  sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can adapt this to my use.